# keyboard wont show up in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

keyboard wont show up in [webview_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter)
help any fixes or should I use some other plugin
[flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)
does this plugin show keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) shows keyboard.

```
WebviewScaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,...)
```

makes the input field show up above keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

someone has a PR to fix this problem ,waiting for it
 :(     this is the link https://github.com/flutter/engine/pull/8687

Answer (score 0):

Also, replacing Scaffold with the Container solve the issue. Only use with when you are not using AppBar.